# Unable to copy file "C:\...\packages\...WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0...System.Web.Http.dll"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am working with ASP.Net MVC4 and I am getting the following error while building the application:

**Unable to copy file "C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Dia\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll" to "bin\System.Web.Http.dll". Access to the path 'bin\System.Web.Http.dll' is denied.**

I don't understand what is this error being new in development. Tried to google but seems like no match cming up.

Comment: Stop the ASP.NET Development Server. Also, where is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: I don't know what is it, so what am I supposed to try? Question is I am getting the error and I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can remove your code from the question to keep it nicer. It is irrelevant such as it isn't something in your code as well as a building problem with VS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Close VS.
2. Delete `bin` and `obj` directories of each project in solution (mainly the one with the building error).
3. Open solution in VS.
4. Clean solution.
5. Rebuild

Comment: This is a bit of shotgun debugging. For me, ten out of ten times errors like this occurs, a stray ASP.NET Development Server is running on my system, keeping files locked. Simply stopping that server will do the trick. Also a Clean will empty the `bin` and `obj` folders, so that step is a bit redundant.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Yes, it is a shotgun. However tons of times with this strange errors is the development server (as you said) or some other process that is still running and shouldn't. Also, sometimes the clean fails to remove some of the files in bin directory.